# Как сделать, чтобы был сразу правильный путь для запуска приложения вебпак

Tags: visual-studio-code, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Открыла папку с приложением, чтобы запустить открываю консоль там пишу путь cd my-app и потом npm start, можно ли сделать, чтобы когда открываю консоль мне не нужно было писать cd my-app, а сразу, чтобы оказывалась в этом пути, как на скрине 2.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно. Перенесите всё содержимое папки `my-app` туда, куда вам нужно. Например, на скриншоте это папка `testenv33`. После чего достаточно будет открыть ту папку в VSC, и можно сразу запускать приложеие.

Comment: а можно, как то программно прописать чтобы открывалась сразу нужна папка?

Comment: Ну можете написать bash-скрипт (или любой другой), в котором выполните команду `cd "C:\\0 program\00 Разработка\testenv33\my-app"`, если делать нечего.